# Parse URI Arguments on ShellTile on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm in the process of developing my first Windows Phone 7 Application. I'm freshfaced to Silverlight, C# and the whole .NET Scene, but I like to think I'm making decent progress.

I know from various code examples, I can set the tile using ShellTile. I know I can pass through params with the URI (Like this example):

```
ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?DefaultTitle=FromSecondaryTile", UriKind.Relative), tile );
```

Can anyone point me in the direction (or explain) how I can handle arguments passed from the tile? So, when the tile's open, I'd like to open a certain part of the application.

For the record, I'm aware I could create a separate page for each one to handle it that way, but I can see that getting messy fast :)

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way I've found that works well for my particular purpose, is the same means of passing values between xaml pages, which is simply to pass them through in the query string:
    NavigationContext.QueryString["XXXXX"].ToString();

Where XXXXX is the name in the key/name pair.

Answer (score 1):

You can either set the url to a seperate page (like `OtherPage.xaml`) or you can use the supplied URI, and change the page/view in the `OnNavigatedTo` override.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Here the NavigationEventArgs will provide you with the navigation args you supplied, as a regular dictionary. From those, you can decide what to do then.

Also, you can make life easier with a simple extension (here specialized with a overload for a integer key, since I personally prefer use them for identifiers)

```
namespace System.Windows.Navigation
{
    public static class NavigationExtensions
    {
        public static int? TryGetKey(this NavigationContext source, string key)
        {
            if (source.QueryString.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                string value = source.QueryString[key];

                int result = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(value, out result))
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public static string TryGetStringKey(this NavigationContext source, string key)
        {
            if (source.QueryString.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return source.QueryString[key];
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you've said Claus makes alot of sense, however I'm stuck pulling the information from NavigationEventArgs, in the first instance if I could even just get it to spit out whats being passed through in text format, I can handle it.. Have you any examples of actually parsing the args to text?

Comment: A way I've found that works well for my particular purpose, is the same means of passing values between xaml pages, which is simply to pass them through in the query string:

    NavigationContext.QueryString["XXXXX"].ToString();

Where XXXXX is the name in the key/name pair.

Comment: Yeah, that's the recommended way of doing it.