# Parsing out query parameters from Live Tile as NameValueCollection while in background agent

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm parsing out the query parameters as a NameValueCollection from an uri based on a ShellTile.NavigationUri property. While in the context of a background agent I don't have access to the NavigationContext as described here: [Parse URI Arguments on ShellTile on Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7851734/346995).

Is there any api available similar to System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString for Windows Phone? This is easily achieved by string operations, but I'm just curious to know any alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can get the Uri from the tile, you can still split the `Query` by "&" and then split each element that returns by "=" to create the NameValueCollection yourself.

Comment: Yes, that's a pretty elegant solution. Seems like there's no ParseQueryString alternative though.